# GeoServer update 2.19.5 -> 2.20.7 won't start in Tomcat with external datadir

Tags: geoserver, update

I am trying to update our GeoServer to the newest version by incremental updates between each major release. Currently moving from 2.19.5 to 2.20.7.

GeoServer 2.20.7 starts fine with its default settings. I am running on Tomcat9 and java 8. When I use an external DATA_DIR the server won't start. Version 2.19.5 starts fine pointing to the same DATA_DIR as I want to use for 2.20.7.

I tried with 2.20.6 and 2.21.4 which also failed.

I am not used to Java in general and I am struggling to find the relevant error so I know how to fix it.

I am looking in the Tomcat9/logs/catalina.txt

The first severe log message is this
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.jna.Structure$2] (value [com.sun.jna.Structure$2@19375f8]) and a value of type [com.sun.jna.Structure.StructureSet] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.`
I am no sure if that is relevant or not?

```
Windows 10
Apache Tomcat/9.0.72
JVM Version: 1.8.0_361-b09
```

Comment: That is probably not the issue as it's occurring on shutdown - does the user running tomcat have write permissions to the data directory? Did you change anything else, like the tomcat version?

Comment: I am doing the update on my local computer to which i have full write access to the folder. I have been deploying the war file in the same tomcat through the whole process. Migrating from 2.13, 2.14, 2.15 etc.. moving from 2.19->2.20 is where I have run into the only issue

Comment: Java 8 is no longer supported, so try with Java 11